# Editing excel in java WorkbookFactory

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi everyone I want to edit an excel sheet from java but my ide can't find "WorkbookFactory".

`InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(filename);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);`

How can I do that?
I've import poi-3.17.jar 
I work on JDeveloper 12.2.1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) is actually in the `poi-ooxml-3.17.jar` library. You will need to add both to your classpath. If you are using maven, use this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, i should missed it.